# Is it possible to use Visual Studio for Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure. I would like to learn the architecture deployed in my company which i shown below on diagram. Can anyone point me to some video example or something that could reflect that from diagram below. I also have access to Azure portal that i have some money credit so if it is possible i could create some test environment based on that diagram.

P.S Is it possible to use Visual Studio for any kind of work based on that diagram or everything have to be created and develop from Azure portal?

```
Datasource Oracle DB --> on prem gateway --> ADF--> Azure DB --> AAS --> PowerBI
SQL EDP --------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Most all the heavy lifting is done in Azure Data Factory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction where most of the transformation takes place. There is a Visual Studio plug-in for Azure Data Factory: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/adf-v2-visual-tools-enabled-in-public-preview/

Comment: you mentioned about ADF, can you shortly descibe it in easy language what is it for, could you also do same for "on prem gateway" and AAS? Could you also explain the diagram they deployed why this one?

Comment: ADF is Azure Data Factory, which allows you to build data pipelines that connect source data with destination data store and allows you to transform data and automate the data loading.

Comment: one ADF per one datasource or could be just one ADF for many sources? Second question what is on premises gateway>

Answer (score 1):

You've got a fairly straightforward BI architecture there with the following logical components:

- raw / source data
- integration
- data mart / dimensional model
- semantic
- visualisation

The physical components look a bit like this:

[image: physical components]

The physical components can be described like this:

- Oracle database - former market leader database product.  I would guess your employers have rejected OBIEE for some reason
- Self-hosted Integration Runtime (SHIR)<s>On-premises data gateway</s> - the SHIR <s>gateway</s> enables the movement of data from on-prem data sources to the cloud.  This **must** be used when moving data from on-prem to Azure SQL DB using Data Factory.  Use the SHIR with Data Factory and the Gateway with Power BI and Azure Analysis Services.
- Data Factory - Azure ELT tool for moving data from place to place.  ETL feature [Data Flow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_XdZLaz00WM) currently in preview.
- Azure SQL DB - PaaS SQL database, scalable via service tiers.  If your data in Oracle is not already in a data mart / dimensional format, then it can be made so here
- Azure Analysis Services (AAS) - PaaS OLAP in-memory engine, scalable for fast slice-and-dice, drill down and semantic modelling.  Tabular only.
- Power BI - increasingly powerful visualisation tool.  Run dashboard in DirectQuery / LiveConnection mode to avoid entirely duplicating the tabular model from AAS in Power BI.

In answer to some of your questions: you can have one Azure Data Factory with many **pipelines**.  The Visual Studio Azure Data Factory project type is now defunct.

As to "why" for certain technologies:

- why Oracle - Who knows.
- why SHIR - SHIR is compulsory when moving data from on-prem to cloud with ADF
- why Azure SQL DB - lightweight and powerful PaaS DB requiring no infra and low TCO; scalable.  Might be location for restructuring of data from raw / relational structure to dimensional in readiness for semantic layer if your data is not already in that format in Oracle
- why AAS - fast, in-memory slice-and-dice; scalable, can pause, can be interrogated by Excel, Power BI Desktop, SSMS, VS, other clients etc.  Optionally has row-level security (RLS)
- Power BI - online service Power BI.com offers easy sharing within organisation, even externally.
- why all the components together - you could (in theory) go straight from Oracle to Power BI with a Power BI gateway (I think) BUT you would then have to do all the modelling in Power BI and your model is then only really accessible from Power BI.  In this model, users with SQL skills can query the data mart, users with DAX (or Excel, or Power BI Desktop) skills can query the AAS tabular model, AAS is very scalable component, etc

These opinions are strictly my own personal ones and the value of them may go down, as well as up.

HTH

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57931638/how-can-i-use-cookie-free-domains-in-the-portal-azure

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory has a 1:M capability with various data sources. One instance of Azure Data Factory will support multiple data movement capabilities: [Data movement activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities#data-movement-activities)

Information about On-Premise Gateway:

> The on-premises data gateway acts as a bridge, providing secure data transfer between on-premises data sources and your Azure Analysis Services servers in the cloud. In addition to working with multiple Azure Analysis Services servers in the same region, the latest version of the gateway also works with Azure Logic Apps, Power BI, Power Apps, and Microsoft Flow. You can associate multiple services in the same subscription and same region with a single gateway.

[Connecting to on-premises data sources with Azure On-premises Data Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-gateway)

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57931638/how-can-i-use-cookie-free-domains-in-the-portal-azure